# Global Redis Twemproxy Architecture

Tags: node.js, mongodb, architecture, redis, twemproxy

I'm launching a global service on a Node/Mongo/Redis stack. I've got an Architecture question about my Redis/Twemproxy config. Here's the crux of the issue: all of my data is 'global' - that is to say, users from anywhere around the world need to access the same data. Unfortunately, there's it's a ~300ms hop across an ocean - so, to avoid slow reads, I need to host a copy of all my data on a server that's 'local' to the user.

This is pretty easy to accomplish with MongoDB. You simply create a replica set, with members all over the globe, and you set readPreference to 'nearest' (least lag). Done.

However, with Redis/Twemproxy, it's not that easy...

My current solution is to take a serious hit on write performance by writing to every global server (within the req/res cycle). This does lead to faster reads since I can let every user read from a local set of the data. If you do it the other way around, write 'local', read 'global' -- you save a bunch of space (you only have one copy of the data), but reads take a huge performance hit. If I had to choose, I need faster reads.

I've tried creating a 'master' cluster (AMER) and then slaving other 'global' clusters (ASIA, EUROPE) to that, but when I tried to read from the 'global' clusters, it returned nothing. This works with a single Redis instance, so, I'm assuming this has to do with the addition of Twemproxy, and key mapping.

Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas? What's the optimal way to configure a global Redis/Twemprox architecture?

Comment: Joshula, have you found any solution yet? We also want our global users to share one copy of data in MongoDB and Redis. But Redis does not have read nearest option.